# Array or ArraySegment as buffer

Tags: .net, buffer, arrays

Before diving into the question itself, please understand, that I am not in control of the whole food chain here - answers or comments of the "you are doing it wrong" kind won't help, as I need to develop against a given API.

Components, that communicate chunks of raw data, most often do so via buffers of type `byte[]` or `ArraySegment<byte>`. The latter has the big advantage of being able to allocate a big buffer once and for all, then use parts of it via the ArraySegment mechanism to reduce memory allocation, fragmentation and GC problems. Nothing new here.

This comes at a price though: A (possibly foreign, closed-source) component consuming an `ArraySegment<byte>` gets a reference (and thus access) to the complete array, meaning, that if it misbehaves it has the ability to corrupt completly unrelated buffers.

Now:

- An extensive search revealed no mechanism to expose **only** a part of an existing array as a complete array, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756692/arraysegment-returning-the-actual-segment-c-sharp) was the closest I got, still not usable as it is "not an array".
- Inheriting from `System.Array` is not supported.
- Inheriting from `System.ArraySegment<T>` is not supported either.

My chain of questions is (answering one obsoletes the later ones):

- Is there a "tricky" way to present a self-developed wrapper as a `byte[]` to a (foreign) consumer
- Or is there a "tricky" way to present a self-developed wrapper as an `ArraySegment<byte>` to a (foreign) consumer, that will not expose the complete underlying array
- Alternativly, is there a way to inherit from `System.Array`, that I missed
- Again alternativly: Is there a way to create a `byte[]` from an aleady allocated (and pinned) memory region, that I have missed, that will not screw up, if it is GCed

**Edit:**

From the comment I take, I didn't say it expressivly enough. Copying data back and forth is not a solution. It is the crutch I use right now though.

Comment: I assume, copying any data around is not a solution?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth This is what I do right now, and no, it isn't. The performance hit is significant (if not paralysing)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I am very reluctant to leave the managed world (i.e. go really native), but unsafe code is OK.

Comment: I deleted that comment in the meantime because I am not really sure how that would help.

Comment: What type does the third party code actually expect? `byte[]` or `ArraySegment<byte>`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I can have both.

Comment: But only those two? Nothing else? `IList<byte>` or something alike?

Comment: Exactly. If it were an `ISomething` I could just implement that interface.

Comment: Passing a `ArraySegment<T>` for an `IList<T>` (or `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`) means that the consumer only sees the part of the array (the segment) that you want them to see.  If they accept a `IReadOnlyList<T>` (or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`), that means they can't change the list either

Comment: Unfortunately, if they accept only a byte[], then there's nothing you can "wrap" to pass a segment.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** To clarify, your options are

- Rewrite the external library to not hard-code `T[]` / `ArraySegment<T>`
- Choose a different way to segment your buffers so calls to the external library naturally align with buffer sizes
- Accept that your over-sized buffers expose additional data that is vulnerable to corruption by outside code
- Copy data

**Edit 2:** Leaving no doubt

> Is there a "tricky" way to present a self-developed wrapper as a byte[] to a (foreign) consumer

No, you cannot do this.

> Or is there a "tricky" way to present a self-developed wrapper as an ArraySegment to a (foreign) consumer, that will not expose the complete underlying array

No, you cannot do this.

> Alternativly, is there a way to inherit from System.Array, that I missed

No, you cannot do this.

> Again alternativly: Is there a way to create a byte[] from an aleady allocated (and pinned) memory region, that I have missed, that will not screw up, if it is GCed

No, you cannot do this.

---

*Without* changing the external API, this becomes by original answer:

If you are stuck using arrays and wish to prevent other code from accessing the sections of the array outside the allowed bounds, you must do the following:

```
T[] originalData = ...;
int viewStart = ...;
int viewLength = ...;

// use a separate array for the viewable region
T[] view = new T[viewLength];
Array.Copy(originalData, viewStart, view, 0, viewLength);
ArraySegment<T> segment = new ArraySegment<T>(view).

// call other code
...

// apply changes
Array.Copy(view, 0, originalData, viewStart, viewLength);
```

These are the restrictions you were placed under due to the API designer's choice to use `T[]`/`ArraySegment<T>` instead of `IList<T>`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my Question: *"Copying data back and forth is not a solution. It is the crutch I use right now though."*

Comment: In addition to that, I currently use a single (big enough) temp array per thread, to avoid allocating and GCing for every single call. Doing it the given way would be another step back.

Comment: @EugenRieck I didn't misread your question. Your question as posed does not have a solution, so I posted an explanation instead (also note the edit).

Comment: Sorry to say so: #1, 3, 4 are explicitly excluded in the question, #2 was the question. Please elaborate on how to achieve this!

Comment: @EugenRieck You didn't ask about #2. #2 means never allocate such large buffers in the first place. Instead of allocating over-sized buffers, allocate buffers the exact size you will need for calling the external API.

Comment: Which is exactly the second paragraph of my Question. Let's leave it at that and move on - thank you for your "answer", which can be summarized as "I don't know"

Comment: @EugenRieck Please see my Edit 2. If you have further questions please be specific.

Comment: @EugenRieck Also, before claiming that "I don't know", see my answer on the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040118/find-the-length-of-an-array-without-using-the-length-property/2082773#2082773